# Finding isosceles triangles

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of isosceles triangles with integer sides, if no side exceeds 1994.

I first assumed the sides a,a,b.
There will be such a unique triangle iff 2a>b.
Hence, for any a, b can vary from 1 to 2a-1. 
We also have a,b<1995.
I cannot figure out how to proceed to the next part. Do i have to assume angle restrictions as well. Please help me!

Comment: No, you don't have to worry about the angles.  You've found all the restrictions.  Now you just have to do the counting.  What values can $a$ take?  For a particular values of $a$ how many possible values are there for $b?$  Now add up all the answers.

Comment: Yes thanks you sir

Comment: Try [OEIS sequence A077043](http://oeis.org/A077043).